# NVIDIA Control Panel files missing (nvcplui.exe)

Tags: windows, drivers, gpu, nvidia

I wanted to remove Geforce Experience and the Nvidia control panel because I thought that it would fix an issue with my computer where it would 70% of the time freeze after a few minutes of using it after a reboot.

Also you probably should know that I recently switched from a laptop using an `AMD Ryzen 7 3700U With Radeon Vega Mobile` CPU to a PC with an `Intel i7-8700K` CPU and `Geforce RTX 3700` GPU.

##### Uninstallation process

Anyways I deleted Geforce Experience and the Nvidia control panel using BCUninstaller. I would delete the Nvidia drivers and all of the services that started with the name "Nvidia" or "nv" and were signed by Nvidia Corporation. I also looked for Nvidia folders and files in my whole C: drive and removed as many of them as I could, and some of the files I couldn't delete, so I had to use a "Force delete" ability in a program called "Ultra Virus Killer" to remove them.

After a while, I successfully removed Nvidia, and after rebooting there were no autostarting Nvidia processes or services running. There might have been some leftover files and registry entries though.

##### After the uninstall

I uninstalled the Nvidia control panel and Geforce experience and removed registry entries and drivers and services to ensure I didn't have any Nvidia software on my PC.

All of this did not fix my issue so I decided to reinstall the Nvidia components. I still need help with the PC freezing issue, I have no clue how to fix it because I haven't been able to analyze what could be causing the issue. So please just give me some advice.

##### Reninstalling Nvidia software

So now I realize that the Nvidia programs and drivers were not the cause of the PC freezing issue. (I'm not 100% sure).

So I decided to install Geforce Experience back from [this website](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/) using the "Download now" button.

After the installation, I restarted my PC and now I have Geforce experience succesfully installed on my PC and got all of the drivers back without errors.

But every time I restart my PC, I get a message that "Nvidia control panel is not found"

[image: Screenshot of the error]

So I did some research and found out that I have to install the Nvidia control panel from the Microsoft store.

After first removing the Nvidia control panel from the Settings app (Because it was there for some reason) And then rebooting and installing it back from the Microsoft store‎ I don't get the message saying "Nvidia control panel is not found" anymore.

So now it seems that the Nvidia control panel is installed since it shows that it is installed in the Microsoft store, and I see the Nvidia control panel in my start menu.

###### But when I try to open the Nvidia control panel itself, I get an error saying that `C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\NVlDlACorp.NVlDlAControlPanel_8.1.964.O_x64_56jybvy8sckcu\nvcplui.exe` Was not found.

I think that I removed this exact file when I was previously uninstalling Geforce Experience.
And somehow the `nvcplui.exe` file did not get regenerated when I reinstalled the Nvidia control panel from the Microsoft store or in the Geforce Experience installation process.

I went to the `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` directory and actually found a folder named `NVIDIACorp.NVIDIAControlPanel_8.1.964.0_x64__56jybvy8sckqj` but inside it, there was no `nvcplui.exe` file. I only found these files that you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

##### Can someone tell me how to get `nvcplui.exe` file back or explain now to get a copy of it?

I searched my whole drive for `nvcplui.exe` and found nothing. (Because I deleted it while uninstalling Nvidia components before).

And the "Control Panel Client" folder is missing in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\`.

Answer (score 1):

You may install [NVIDIA Control Panel through the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NF8H0H7WMLT).

If your issue remains unresolved, you may need to reinstall the latest driver from https://www.nvidia.com/drivers After downloading the appropriate driver for your GPU and OS, use the Advanced installation option along with a clean installation.

Comment: I did install the Nvidia control panel from the Microsoft store, and I reinstalled the Nvidia drivers and clicked the clean install checkbox and it did not regenerate the file that I forcefully deleted.

Comment: Interesting... this sounds like a permissions issue that's causing the installer to silently fail. You shouldn't be able to browse to or gain permissions of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps by default. So it seems like your uninstaller process borked something. If you have a restore point from before you did the registry changes, etc. it may be invaluable, go back to it. Otherwise you can try removing that folder, runnning  _sfc /scannow_ from an elevated command prompt, reboot, and then perform the clean installation again. If it continues to fail, suggest reinstalling Windows.

Comment: The uninstaller left me with so many leftovers that I decided to remove some of them manually, and it turns out that I shouldn't have deleted the files that were protected in the "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" folder, because they were not regenerated properly for some reason.

Comment: When I was uninstalling the Nvidia components I used this https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4223 to help me clean up the Nvidia components. It said to delete these registry entries "HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Logging" and "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\NVIDIA Corporation\Logging" But instead I removed the whole "NVIDIA Corporation" registry keys instead of the "Logging" subkeys. After the Nvidia reinstall I have both of the registry keys regenerated. I did not remove manually any other registry keys to my knowledge.

Comment: Based on your comment on the other answer, `I sent the hard disk to my relative who would clone the files and registry to the new PC` I'd strongly suggest a clean installation of Windows. You'll want to back up any important files to external/cloud storage. Windows is not intended as a portable OS, and although portability has improved through Windows versions over time, moving a Windows install from one set of hardware to another is not recommended.

Comment: That could be the cause, but it seems like the freezing issue just started happening after a day of me installing software and stuff and twerking with some group policy options that I found. And the Nvidia issue is because I deleted a protected file when it clearly had a purpose to be protected, but I still think that the nvcplui.exe file should be there after reinstalling the Nvidia components. I mean when my relative installed Geforce Experience on my PC why did it then generate the "nvcplui.exe" file but not now when I try to do it?

Comment: It most likely failing due to permissions. The NVIDIA Control Panel is seperate from the driver or GFE. The driver only recently began to seamlessly install NVCP from the SDH driver.

Comment: I was able to restore the nvcplui.exe file (along with some other files from Nvidia) from the "C:\$Recycle.Bin" folder using "Everything." I am not posting an answer to this post because I technically didn't find a solution to regenerate the Nvcplui.exe file, I just got lucky and the file wasn't permanently deleted yet and I was able to just restore it. (The Nvidia control panel now works!)

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information along with instructions on how to install the NVIDIA control panel utility on [here](https://www.nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/)

My recommendation is to do a clean or fresh install. When you removed the factory install NVIDIA utility on a rush, the software may have been tied to other hardware or software utilities/programs and that interoperability was interrupted.

Also, I would recommend not to mess with the registry unless you know what you're doing. You could corrupt core software programs and even the OS itself in extreme cases.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation didn't help and I still have not found a way to get that one file to the folder. I have no idea what even generated it there in the first place.

Comment: @SalmonSnake it should've worked as it is from the manufacturer. What's concerning to me is that you don't know what created the files. Did you buy your computer used or new? If you bought new, do you have the manual?

Comment: My laptop was physically broken and I sent my laptop to a company that cloned the SSD from the broken laptop into a hard disk or something. Then they sent me the broken laptop and the hard disk. Then I decided to buy a new PC so I sent the hard disk to my relative who would clone the files and registry to the new PC that I would buy and he also installed Geforce Experience.
‎ ‎
Previously I didn't that I should tell you guys all that to make the comment shorter, but now you know where the Geforce Experience was installed.
‎ 
(The PC started to freeze after about two weeks of using it btw)

Comment: @SalmonSnake ok. Your old laptop may have had hardware different from your current laptop. The registry cloning could work if you reinstall the SSD back into the original laptop (not always true). You see the SSD clone was compatible with the old laptop software and hardware setup. Even if you bought a similar laptop, hardware components and configurations may differ from the broken laptop. Since the laptop was broken, your best case was to use the clone SSD to copy your personal files (non registry files) and start fresh by making a clean install OS on the new laptop.

Comment: I am almost certain that the SSD clone does not have anything to do with the freezing issue since this PC was not doing the freezing at all for a few weeks after I got this, it started to do it one day when I did something wrong when using my system. The day after the freezing issue started happening, I remember thinking "I must have done something wrong yesterday that caused this issue" Because I did tweak my registry and did stuff like tweaking options on my system that day. And the Nvidia issue is because of my actions and does not have anything to do with the SSD cloning.

Comment: @SalmonSnake you're correct. Changing or tweaking the registry erroneously is totally possible within the realm of possibilities of why your laptop does not work correctly now. I noted this in my answer. Coming back from a bad registry modification is hard. It's easier to start fresh with a clean OS install.